# Import JavaScript file with semicolons and spaces

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import

I'm using vue JavaScript 2.5, there is grammar to not use semicolons, extra spaces etc., when I'm trying to import "normal" JavaScript library I got errors like:

```
Extra semicolon
Missing space before function parentheses 
A constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter
```

Is there any way to avoid it?

I'm importing as:

```
import queryParser from '@/libs/parser/query'
```

Comment: Those look like ESLint style errors, you can configure it to ignore specific files or folders: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories

Comment: thanks a lot ! i tried to configure eslintrc.js but not ignorefile